# How to send a NULL through a Socket in Borland C++

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I have a requirement of sending a string value to a specific ipAddress but the string value should enclose with two `Ascii Null` Values.
Eg: `NULL + message + NULL`

I managed to send the message using `sck->Socket->SendText(Edit1->Text);` but I don't know how to send a NULL value through the `SocketClient` component. It does not need to be the Send Text method. Any method that allows to send a data packet with two NULL characters enclose with will do.

I'm fairly new to C++. If any one can help me out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
void __fastcall TFrmCageCom::Reset(TObject Sender) {
  TClientSocket socket = new TClientSocket(this);
  socket = sockets[1]; // Getting a socket from
  if (socket->Active) {
    String data = GeneratePackect(isNumeric, "", size, false);
    String packet = "@1@2@3@"; // "@" sign necessary to divide each character in
                               // receivers end
    socket->Socket->SendText(packet);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see what you have so far?

Comment: The whole program is bit too long but what I do is load ClientSocket components dynamically for each ipAddress and send the string I need using the SendText Method in Socket
        socket->Socket->SendText(packet);

Comment: Still, you need to provide at least enough details to actually know what `Edit1` and the corresponding `Text` member are? And what `sck`/`Socket` is, of course? Some VCL I assume? `AnsiString`/`UnicodeString`?

Comment: Can you make a smaller program _(try to actually build it)_ that **just** creates a message and sends `NULL + message + NULL` over a socket?  And show us that?

Comment: void __fastcall TFrmCageCom::Reset(TObject *Sender)
{
   TClientSocket* socket = new TClientSocket(this);
   socket = sockets[1]; // Getting a socket from

   if(socket -> Active)
   {
        String data =  GeneratePackect(isNumeric,"", size, false);
        String packet = "@1@2@3@"; // "@" sign necessary to divide each character in receivers end
        socket->Socket->SendText(packet);
   }
}

Comment: @Vortex: I'm not sure what that `String` class would be (again, it's not Standard C++), but it'd be worth trying `String packet = "\0@1@2@3\0";` - it might "just" work....

Comment: @Vortex: I tried to add the code you posted in your comment. Please check that it looks OK. Or edit your question. In the future, please don't post large code snippets in comments, in particular if they should be part of the question in the first place. Instead edit your question. Anyway: What is that String class? Unicode or Ansi?

Comment: @TonyD initializing *anything* from a string literal, must stop reading at a null byte, otherwise how does it know when to stop reading?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: not so... a constructor taking a reference-to-array of template-parameter-size-N handles that easily....

Comment: ok.. nearly anything :) `String` has no template member functions however.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: yup - you've dug harder than I to find these class APIs (and got my +1 for it a while back).  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what type `Edit1->Text` is, so you might need to do something below to convert to a `const char*` to an ASCIIZ buffer or to a `std::string`.  It seems like `SendBuf` supports binary transmission - see http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0004/Using_sockets.htm?PHPSESSID=ec48204948f2965316eec877d313d231

```
#include <string>

std::string s("\0");
s += Edit1->Text;       // <--- not sure about this line!
s += '\0';
sck->Socket->SendBuf(s.data(), s.size());
```

That said, this socket library is not part of Standard C++, so for this kind of question finding some Borland-specific library documentation is necessary.

Comment: Well, `Edit1` sounds like some VCL Control, which might be using a `wchar_t` string class (`UnicodeString`). Or not, depending on the version of the compiler. So `s += Edit1->Text.c_str()` might work, or not... @Vortex didn't really provide any details here...

Comment: `?PHPSESSID=ec48204948f2965316eec877d313d231` Lol at session in GET parameter

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `TClientSocket` is not part of Borland C++.  It's a part of the VCL library, which is packaged with C++Builder and Delphi; both of which are different products to Borland C++.   It would be good to mention which product and which version you are using (this socket library has undergone changes over the years -- as has `String`).

`TClientWinSocket::SendText` is for sending a `String`. So your options are:

1. Embed the null bytes in the `String`.
2. Use a different send function.

Did you try reading [the documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBEROVERVIEW_ScktComp_TClientWinSocket.html) (or using code insight)? You can send raw bytes by using `SendBuf`:

```
socket->Socket->SendBuf( "", 1 );
socket->Socket->SendText( packet );
socket->Socket->SendBuf( "", 1 );
```

Alternatively, since `String` has an `operator+` overload and an implicit constructor from `char`, so you can write:

```
socket->Socket->SendText( '\0' + packet + '\0');
```

---

Some other comments. The code you posted is illegal:

```
 TClientSocket socket = new TClientSocket(this);
```

You cannot have automatically allocated VCL objects, this should fail to compile.  I wonder if you meant this to be `TClientSocket *socket = new TClientSocket(this)`.  (If so, please copy-paste your code in instead of typing out stuff from memory, who knows what other subtle differences there are between what you have posted and what your real code is).

If you did mean what I suggested, then you have a bug because:

```
socket = sockets[1];
```

makes `socket` point to `sockets[1]`, and not to the socket you just `new`'d.  (Using the assignment operator with pointers in C++ means to change where the pointer is pointing; in general if you want to do an object assignment you'd need to write `*ptr = *other_ptr;`. VCL objects are mostly non-copyable however).

Next, the behaviour of `Edit1->Text` depends on whether you are using Unicode or not. It could be a narrow string or a wide string. You should include this information when posting your question.